# Iterate through non-queryset dictionary in a template

Tags: django, django-templates

I have a dictionary that I am feeding into a chart.js line chart.

It looks as follows:

```
context['graph_data'] = {'day': [datetime.date(2022, 2, 28),
  datetime.date(2022, 3, 1),
  datetime.date(2022, 3, 2),
  datetime.date(2022, 3, 3),
  datetime.date(2022, 3, 4),
  datetime.date(2022, 3, 5),
  datetime.date(2022, 3, 6),
  datetime.date(2022, 3, 7),
  datetime.date(2022, 3, 8),
  datetime.date(2022, 3, 9),
  datetime.date(2022, 3, 10),
  datetime.date(2022, 3, 11),
  datetime.date(2022, 3, 12),
  datetime.date(2022, 3, 13),
  datetime.date(2022, 3, 14),
  datetime.date(2022, 3, 15),
  datetime.date(2022, 3, 16),
  datetime.date(2022, 3, 17),
  datetime.date(2022, 3, 18),
  datetime.date(2022, 3, 19)],
 'response_totals': [0,
  0,
  0,
  0,
  12,
  12,
  1,
  0,
  0,
  0,
  0,
  0,
  0,
  0,
  0,
  0,
  1,
  0,
  0,
  0]}
```

The template section that I am getting tripped up on looks like the following:

```
new Chart(ctx1, {
      type: "line",
      data: {
        labels: [{%for i in graph_data%}{{i.day}},{%endfor%}],
        datasets: [{
            label: "Referrals",
            tension: 0.4,
            borderWidth: 0,
            pointRadius: 2,
            pointBackgroundColor: "#cb0c9f",
            borderColor: "#cb0c9f",
            borderWidth: 3,
            backgroundColor: gradientStroke1,
            data: [{%for j in graph_data%}{{j.response_totals}},{%endfor%}],
            maxBarThickness: 6
          },
```

I am a bit of a newbie. I can handle querysets but I'm not sure how to transform non-qs dictionaries via the template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a few ways to write this, first read up on [the documentation for django template language](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/templates/language/#variables).

Hopefully you understand that to get the list of days stored as a value against the `day` key in python you would do something like `context['graph_data']['day']`.

In the template we use `.` to access dictionary keys, so we can use `graph_data.day` in the template to get the same list of days that `context['graph_data']['day']` would produce in python.

So I would do it like this:

```
new Chart(ctx1, {
    ...
    data: {
        labels:[{% for i in graph_data.day %}{{ i }},{% endfor %}],
        ...
    }
}
```